# how can i know from gmail/fb login form that user has successfully logged in, when parent and child windows are from the different origin?

Tags: jquery, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

Rails 4 + Twitter Bootstrap + jquery + javascript + Ominiauth
[image]
_login_form.html.erb

```
    <div style="border-right: 1px solid #C0C0C0; margin-left: -11px; float: left; height: 252px"></div>
      <h4>Sign In with</h4></br>
      <a><%= link_to image_tag("web/fb_login.png", :alt => "facebook", :style => 'margin: 0 0 10% 20%'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), :class => "popup", :"data-width" => 600, :"data-height" => 400, :onclick => "return closeloginform();" %> </a><br/><br/>
      <a><%= link_to image_tag("web/google_login.png", :alt => "google", :style => 'margin: 0 0 0 20%'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2), :class => "popup", :"data-width" => 600, :"data-height" => 500, :onclick => "return closeloginform();" %></a><br/><br/>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function closeloginform(){
    $('#popup_div').modal('hide');
  }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function popupCenter(url, width, height, name) {
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(width/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(height/2);
    childWindow = window.open(url, name, "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width="+width+",height="+height+",toolbar=no,left="+left+",top="+top);
    return childWindow;
  }

  $("a.popup").click(function(e) {
    popupCenter($(this).attr("href"), $(this).attr("data-width"), $(this).attr("data-height"), "authPopup");
    e.stopPropagation(); return false;
});
</script>
```

1) On Header Sign In Link is there.

2) When i will click on Sign in it will open a modal popup (twitter bootstrap).

3) Two options will be there for google(image LOGO) and facebook(image LOGO) sign in.

4) when you will click on any one (suppose google image means sign in with gmail account) then a window will open with gmail login form.

5) There i will enter login details then **What should happen after successful login** child window should close with reloading the parent window. **What is happening after successful login** only child window is reloading and getting successfully sign in in child window.

My question how can i know from gmail/fb login form that user has successfully logged in ??

Answer (score 0):

One of the oauth2 flows specifies that you provide a redirect path for your oauth login gmail/fb login. This redirect path is on your domain and after successful login gmail/fb will redirect the user back to this path appended with an auth token.

```
 #redirect path for fb
 https://my.page.com/auth/fb/callback

 #fb will redirect after form submit to url like this
 https://my.page.com/auth/fb/callback?token=aasnacdsjviavianvashnvoasuh&&other=important_fb_stuff
```

The token and other info identifying this user uniquely at fb will be within `auth_hash`. If this was the first time this user signed in, you then create a new record otherwise load the user with this fb_id and authenticate hime within the session

Watch [#241 Simple OmniAuth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth)

**Edit 1**

Use `role="dialog"` on bootstrap `.modal`, in order to load an overlay div instead of opening a child window. Redirects will then affect the whole page

Comment: Yes Dre-hh but in my case it is logging in on the child window but i want child window should close and parent window should reload, and user should log in ,,,,any suggestion.....

Comment: Now i see. You don't have to open a new `window`. Those cannot be controlled by the opener. However you can access the `window.opener` form the window (in order to reload the opener for instance). But if you just use bootstrap modal with `role="dialog"`, it will simply fade in a relative positioned overlay div, pretending to be a window. If a redirect happens then after login, the complete page will be rerendered according to what you do in the rails action with path mapping to /auth/fb/callback. I would just redirect again to root page there.

Comment: Not getting what to do.. :(

Comment: Looked at this again. Are you trying to open the FB Login form page also in a new popup window.? This is very unusual. Just keep the 'login with fb'  button in the bootstrap modal dialog and attach a direct link to the fb oauth page with the login form on it. Check out imdb's login page. It's exactly the same. But i can also think of a solution how to do it in the popup. I would just render a view with js content 'window.close' on your redirect action